# Как добавить класс в <c:url>?

Tags: html, css, jsp, jstl

Вот мой линк

```xml
<a class="btn btn-outline-light mt-3 btn-lg" href="/menu">Name</a>
```

Я хочу переделать это в `<c:url>` чтобы использовать `<c:param>`
Например, вот так, но тут не могу понять, как добавить class, чтобы использовать css

```
<c:url value="/menu">
     <c:param name="Id" value="736"/>
     <c:param name="user" value="example"/>
</c:url>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-light mt-3 btn-lg" 
   href="<c:url value="/menu">
           <c:param name="Id" value="736"/>
           <c:param name="user" value="example"/>
         </c:url>">Name</a>
```

Comment: Если мой ответ помог решить вашу проблему, то надо отметить его как принятый, так будет легче искать нужный ответ, плюс к тому, что за это ещё дают +2 реп.